# Is the Wall of Stone Spell mistranslated from English to German?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, translations, german

In the English version of the [Wall of Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone) spell the dimension specification of the wall is:

> A wall of stone is 1 inch thick per four caster levels and composed of
>   up to one 5-foot square per level.

This would mean for a 9th level wizard I have 9 squared slabs 2 inches thick.

[In German this](http://prd.5footstep.de/Grundregelwerk/Zauber/Steinwand) is:

> Die Wand ist pro vier Zauberstufen 2,50 cm stark und nimmt eine Fläche
>   von bis zu 1 Würfel pro Zauberstufe mit jeweils 1,50 m Kantenlänge
>   ein.

This would mean I have 9 cubes and can form them into 5 cm thick slabs, which is a huge difference.

The translation (as far as I can see) of the second part would be "one cube with 1.5 m edge length per caster level."

Even though I am quite sure this is wrong, I would like to have this verified since I am not an English native speaker. Since this translation is wrong in all published editions I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The German version contradicts itself as it states:

> ...eine Fläche von bis zu 1 Würfel...

Fläche describes something with 2 dimensions while Würfel describes something with 3 dimensions. Just ignore the Würfel part or replace it with Quadrat and you are good. The thickness is just rounded and should not make a real difference and 1,5m is always used in the german version for 5ft.

The correct translation (using the usual equivalencies/ roundings) would be:

> Die Wand ist pro vier Zauberstufen 2,50 cm stark und nimmt ein Quadrat mit einer Fläche von 1,5m x 1,5m pro Zauberstufe ein.

Comment: Thanks for backing me up here. I dropt paizo a line so they can put it into the errata and corret this in the next edition.